# Disable stop share prompt box during screen sharing by getDisplayMedia()

Tags: node.js, browser, webrtc, screen-capture, get-display-media

I am sharing screen by getDisplayMedia()

My screen sharing feature is working fine

[screen shot of screen sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXhS4.png)

In the above screenshot you can see a bydefault prompt box of stop share is appeared .
I want to disable that prompt box how i can disable that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can not disable this box for security/ux reasons. This box offers the user a way to end screen sharing, your website might not offer such a button.